# Anomaly finder using autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

We're using the following architecture for anomaly-finding-

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(80,80,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6))

#-----------------#

model.add(Dense(32,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(51200,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape ((20 ,20 ,128)))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D ((2 ,2)))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D ((2 ,2)))
model.add(Conv2D (3,  kernel_size =(3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Reshape ((3 ,6400)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Reshape ((80,80,3)))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

We've two sets of images, 1000 images of [TypeA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuwM8.jpg) & 5400 images of [TypeB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQBxh.jpg)

Now when we're training our autoencoder on typeB images and testing on typeA images, mean square error of typeB is coming out to be greater than that of typeA. Since, they are visually different, mse in case of typeB should have been smaller than that of typeA.

Is there any problem in my architecture? What should I change in the architecture to get the result right? Please suggest...

Comment: This layer seems wrong: model.add(Dense(51200,  activation='relu'))

Comment: What is the input size? 80,80,3 ?

Comment: Yes, input size is 80,80,3. But why are you saying the layer, 'model.add(Dense(51200, activation='relu'))' is wrong? What do you suggest- shall I remove the layer?

Comment: Yes remove that. And change the following Reshape such that you get same dimensions as before the Flatten in the encoder part of the network

Comment: In your input you seem to have RGB data. But the images you show seem to have some sort of intensity values for each hexagonal area. Can you output those intensities as grayscale instead - that will make the architecture simpler

Comment: It also seems that you are using some plots of data as the input to a visual anomaly detector. If you have access to the underlying data, I would recommend not plot the data - but instead do anomaly detection directly on the (2d) vectors

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try these out. Just a bit of clarification- are you suggesting to remove the 'dense 51200' layer because  that layer is breaking the symmetry of decoder and encoder part?

Comment: Mainly because the expansion from 32 to 51200 features does not make much sense. Unlikely to be enough information there to fill this layer meaningfully, and probably there will be a lot of redundant , random, and/or dead neurons there. These might cause trouble when using out-of-distribution data